# Regex to target a page but not its children

Tags: regex, redirect

I'm trying to write a regular expression to target a URL but not any of its children. My regex is definitely pretty weak and could use some help.

Page I want to target (may include trailing slash and or UTM parameters): https://test.com/deals/
Example of a page I do not want to target: https://test.com/deals/Best-Sellers/c/901

My attempt:

```
.*Deals\/((?!Best).)*
```

Comment: You have Best in your pattern, do you mean that Best can not be directly after `Deals/` ? https://regex101.com/r/beXPnK/1/

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/1eHKan/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\/deals\/?(?:[?#]\S*)?$`

[Check on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T2Hj3b/4)

This is a bit more permissive than what your question suggests but it might come in handy.

The main thing is that it tries to match `/deals` at the end of the line. This ensures that you won't match, say `https://test.com/best-deals` or similar but *only* the URL that ends with `/deals`. Also, the final `/` is optional - you might get `https://test.com/deals`.

In addition to that, the regex allows for the URL to end with `#` anchors or `?` followed by parameters. The page might allow this right now or in the future - for example, if a link is used that leads to the same page (e.g. to a specific section), you'd get a `#` added to the URL. Or there might be something like a filter configuration embedded in the URL `https://test.com/deals/?sort=price&productsPerPage=15&page=2&minPrice=100`.

Finally, you should make your regex case insensitive to account for the fact the URL might also be `https://test.com/Deals/`. How you set this flag will depend on where you are using the regex, so I am just adding this as a reminder.